# how I can Fix this error (migrate to sql azure)

Tags: sql-server, migration, azure-sql-database

I get an error `TOTAL_WRITE is not supported in current version` when i try validate my database from sql server migration in to sql azure. How I can Fix this error migrate to sql azure

Also I git this error `sp_spaceused` is not supported in current version of Azure *SQL Database*

```
StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_sizetables] -- 'db_name
```

Comment: These look like three separate questions -- for us to help here, please ask them three times.  In general, note that Azure doesn't support all features of SQL Server, so it may be that you need to re-write some of your stored procedures appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences between SQL Server and SQL Database that need to be accounted for when migrating from on-prem to the cloud. 
For more information please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee730904.aspx

In this case, several builtin functions are only applicable for SQL Server on Prem. You will need to remove them from your SPs before migrating to the cloud.

Also, for the most complete compatibility with SQL Server, make sure that you have a V12 Database on SQL Azure. For more details check http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/